# Access Google Transfer Service

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am unable to locate Cloud Transfer service over my GCP account.
Can any one please help me how i can access transfer service.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is in the `Data Transfer` menu, right under the `Storage` menu entry in the main hamburger menu:

[image]

[image]

The access to this service used to be in the `Storage` menu, but was promoted to its own main menu entry with the rest of data transfer options.

Please, verify that you have the [required permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console#before-starting) to access that functionality.

Comment: @Vibhor Were you able to access the Transfer Service functionality finally?